# Full width centered menu bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a menu in **Bootstrap** using below **HTML** & **CSS**, I wanted to create full width centered menu, the code below is showing that it breaks when I add a 5th menu item, it is working well with 4 items.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%;">
        <li id="set_width" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
#set_width {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

in my case the menu is dynamic, what can be the best CSS for this?

Comment: 25% is 4 parts of 100%, 20% is 5 parts... use `#set_width {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}`

Comment: or you can set width based on items count in JQuery, like if you have 4 set width to 25% and if 5 then set it to 20%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is complete solution, you can add as many you want, it will not break :-)

```css
#set_width {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.navbar-nav{
 width:100%; 
 display: flex;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="set_width" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
     <li id="set_width"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, you need to change `id = "set_width"` for example to `class = "set_width"`, because `id` is a unique identifier, and there should be only one on the page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="set_width" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="set_width"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="set_width"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="set_width"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li class="set_width"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
     <li class="set_width"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you can use flex for your task, for example:

```
.navbar-nav {
   display: flex;  
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: No need to repeat class="set_width" to every LI just simply use .navbar-nav li and apply CSS.